# Deployed meteor app to galaxy but why is it not showing?

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

The purpose of the below steps is to test a simple deploy process with a bare bones app before I commit my time (I've already spent a week with meteor and I love it but went through hell trying to deploy to heroku etc.. )  Seems like the best way is to just use their galaxy service, .. so there goes I...

First I did a meteor create ramonadsouza in my local drive.  Then, I did:

```
meteor deploy ramonadsouza.meteor.com
```

I checked to make sure I followed all the steps here to ensure high availability:  http://galaxy-guide.meteor.com/high-availability.html

However, my app is not showing at ramonadsouza.meteor.com even though I get the green light UI etc.. 
What did I miss?

Comment: Have you looked at the Galaxy logs? https://galaxy.meteor.com/app/<yourappname>/logs

Comment: I ended up contacting Meteor support which was excellent btw!  I got a demo app, up and running.  Turns out I should have deployed to meteor deploy ramonadsouza.meteorapp.com then it worked fine!

Comment: Great! You should answer your own question then :)